# Alternative Yeast Options for IIPA

Tags: yeast, ipa, ale

I was gifted a 5 gallon Imperial IPA kit which did not come with yeast. It recommends either Safale US-05 Dry Yeast or Omega Yeast OYL009. Times being what they are, Omega is sold out and shipping Safale US-05 won't get it here for 14 days, and costs way more than the yeast itself.

I have White Labs Edinburgh Scottish Ale yeast, Nottingham Dry Ale yeast, and I've got a some Duvel Belgian Golden Ale yeast harvested, as well as their Grand Reserve (whatever those strains are).

Thoughts on what would work well with an IIPA? The only one of these I've used is the Nottingham. I just bottled a small batch of ale using it, but haven't tasted a finished beer. Alternatively, should I go buy some IPA that is bottle conditioned and harvest that?

Cheers!